# Algorithm to do numeric profile of the string

Tags: algorithm, perl

I have few file similar to below, and I am trying to do numeric profiling as mentioned in the image

[image: mumeric profiling methodology]

```
 >File Sample
 attttttttttttttacgatgccgggggatgcggggaaatttccctctctctctcttcttctcgcgcgcg
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaagcgcggcggcgcggasasasasasasaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

I have to map each substring of size 2 and then map it to 33 value for different ptoperties and then add as per the window size of 5.

```
    my  %temp = (
                 aCount => {
                        aa =>2
                 }
                 cCount => {
                        aa => 0
                 }
    );
```

My current implementation include as per below ,

```
   while (<FILE>) {
     my $line = $_;
     chomp $line;

     while ($line=~/(.{2})/og) {
        $subStr = $1;
        if (exists $temp{aCount}{$subStr}) {

          push @{$temp{aCount_array}},$temp{aCount}{$subStr};

          if (scalar(@{$temp{aCount_array}}) == $WINDOW_SIZE) {

                my $sum = eval (join('+',@{$temp{aCount_array}}));
                shift @{$temp{aCount_array}};
                #Similar approach has been taken to other 33 rules
          }

        }

        if (exists $temp{cCount}{$subStr}) {
             #similar approach 
        }

        $line =~s/.{1}//og;
     }
   }
```

is there any other approach to increase the speed of the overall process

Comment: what does this data represent?

Comment: the data represent the scientific values of certain substring  properties eg for xray, aa value 0.091

Comment: I don't believe your problem is speed as the code you show won't work at all. It's not clear how you want to manipulate the data, but it looks like you have confused `aCount` and `cCount`. Your code only ever uses `acount`, and you are using `$temp{aCount}` as both a hash reference and an array reference.

Comment: Please include a *coherent* explanation of what this is supposed to be doing. The image isn't enough, and your code is too broken to glean anything from.

Comment: Explanation of problem -- You have a string eg "atcgatat". You need to make a substring of tuple size 2. So my result, for the above string will be at,tc,cg,ga etc . Each substring can be mapped to 33 different values eg for aCount aa is 2, for cCount aa is 0, U need to sum the value at,tc,cg,ga,at for a specic rule eg aCount for the first 5 substring .. shift the first value and push the a new value and recalculate the sum.. This process is continuous ... Any other approach to fasten the over all process

Comment: @Borodin  : I hope the problem is clear now :)

Comment: @hobbs : I was able to make my point

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are awesome, but they can be overkill when all you need are fixed width substrings. Alternatives are `substr`

```
$len = length($line);
for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i+=2) {
   $subStr = substr($line,$i,2);
   ...
}
```

or `unpack`

```
foreach $subStr (unpack "(A2)*", $line) {
   ...
}
```

I don't know how much faster either of these will be than regular expressions, but [I know how I would find out](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Benchmark).